# How to cause live text wrap while image/element is being dragged, in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, text-editor, word-wrap

I want to make a text editor which incorporates this sort of effect (see video). However, I have no idea how this would be possible with javascript.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYnj4Mz9g9g

Any ideas would be amazing!

Thanks

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I genuinely don't know how to start.. I thought of positioning the image rapidly as it is dragged but this seems too intensive.

Comment: perhaps you should start by telling what js framework you use

Comment: I just use straight js but I guess I can hack any framework if you have an idea??

Comment: Can't think of any way that this is possible.  It would require a way to float an element within a document and not just left and right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're going for is an HTML5 capability, that being said, give this link a read: http://www.greepit.com/2010/06/wrap-text-around-an-image-jqslickwrap/

Comment: Nice thanks, this is very useful, I just need the wrapping to occur as the element is dragged.